# Why is RPM config in /usr/lib/rpm/rpmc and not under /etc/ like other package managers

Tags: rpm

Can anyone please explain to me why the RPM config is under /usr/lib/rpm/rpmc and not located under /etc/ like other package managers, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the convention is that the vendor-supplied settings (operating system) go to `/usr/lib` whereas user settings can override them by placing equivalent files under `/etc`.

A notable example is SystemD unit files in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` vs `/etc/systemd/system`.

If you do `man rpm`, you can find that the files are being checked in `etc` as well:

> rpmrc Configuration
> /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc
> /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/rpmrc
> /etc/rpmrc
> ~/.rpmrc

So the question to why is for customization.

Comment: Thank you, it just was throwing me off. I was hoping that there was an underlying reason to help me memorize it. I'm studying to take the CompTIA Linux+.